# calculations in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, math, operators

Could anyone explain to me why this keeps returning 0 when it should return a value of 42? it works on paper so i know the math is right I'm just wondering as to why it isn't translating across?

```
    int a = 60;
    int b = 120;
    int c = 85;
    int progress;

    progress = ((c-a)/(b-a))*100;

    NSLog(@"Progess = %d %%",progress);
```

Comment: Xcode is a editor, not a calculator

Comment: I'm aware, i was just using this as a way to test out something for quartz 2d

Comment: sure, but still Xcode is not running your code or doing some calculation. It is just an IDE, so your original title was kind of poor.

Comment: Fair enough i see your point, it does make more sense now, cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because your math is all using integers.

In particular, your inner expression is calculating 25 / 60, which in integer math is zero.

In effect you have *over-parenthesised* your expression, and the resulting order of evaluation is causing integer rounding problems.

It would have worked fine if you had just written the formula so:

```
progress = 100 * (c - a) / (b - a);
```

because the 100 * (c - a) would first evaluate to 2500, and would then be divided by 60 to give 41.

Alternative, if any one (or more) of your variables `a`, `b`, or `c` were a `float` (or cast thereto) the equation would also work.

That's because an expression in which *either* operand is a `float` will cause the other (integer) operand to be promoted to a `float`, too, at which point the result of the expression will also be a `float`.

Answer (score 3):

`c - a` will give you 25

`b - a` will give you 60

Since `a`, `b`, and `c` are all integers, meaning they can't be decimals. Therefore, by doing `(c-a)/(b-a)`, you will get 0, instead of 0.41666666 because in integer division, anything after the decimal point will get cut off, leaving the number before the decimal point.

To make it work the way you wanted it to, you should try casting `(c-a)` and `(b-a)` to either double or float:

`progress = ((float)(c-a) / (float)(b-a)) * 100;`

or

`progress = ((double)(c-a) / (double)(b-a)) * 100;`

Answer (score 1):

`a`,`b` and `c` are `int`s. When you calculate `((c-a)/(b-a))`, the result is also an `int`; the real value is a decimal (0.42), but an `int` can't take a decimal number, so it rounds to `0`, which is multiplied by `100` to get `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `(c - a) / (b - a)` is computed using `integer math`.

To fix, cast to a float before dividing:

```
progress = (int)((((float)(c - a)) / ((float)(b - a))) * 100);
```